# Shapely polygon creates straight lines between points where it shouldn't

Tags: python, shapefile, geopandas, shapely

I'm using [shapely](https://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) within Python. I created a polygon using coordinates; however, when I plot it, it creates random straight lines between points where it should not.

Here is what it looks like when I plot it:

[image]

And here is what I want the perimeter to look like (without the fill):

[image]

Here's the code I'm using to create the polygon and plot it:

```
poly_coords = coords[['lon','lat']]
poly_coords = poly_coords.values.tolist()
poly = Polygon(poly_coords)

x,y = poly.exterior.xy
plt.plot(x,y)
```

Is there something I'm missing that's causing the random lines between points to be created?

Comment: Could you share please those coordinates? It doesn't seem like there is a problem with the code.

Comment: Unfortunately, it is thousands of coordinates, and I'm not sure how to upload them here.

Comment: Does this link work?: https://wetransfer.com/downloads/6365e089668ca6e1625402a8a9a32eca20221215184133/83ca0a6c63e1da731731368059c73ec720221215184153/399b0d?trk=TRN_TDL_01&utm_campaign=TRN_TDL_01&utm_medium=email&utm_source=sendgrid

Comment: The coordinate order is problematic. You need to remove problematic coordinates

Comment: How would I go about doing that?

Comment: Is it along the lines of having out of order coordinates within the dataframe/polygon? How do I determine which ones are, if so?

Comment: I am trying to figure it out. :)

Comment: Oh, thank you! Sorry, do not mean to interrupt.

Comment: OK. Those are not the coordinates of a polygon but a multipolygon. There are islands or something like that. It is not clear which coordinate sequence belongs to which part. Look at this image -> https://i.stack.imgur.com/d11dm.png I think it would be easier to solve this problem manually than to solve it using code.

Comment: One possible **short** solution is to get rid of those islands using a GIS software (for example in QGIS) after importing the coordinate as points (usin add delimited text layer) and export as CSV

Comment: Ah, I think I see what you mean. So when plotting those points, shapely is connecting those points thinking it's one big polygon, even though they are smaller polygons separated from the overall polygon then?

Comment: Yes it is. They are separated visually but not separated in the file.

Comment: So there's no possible solution, or quick solution I should say, within Python using shapely or another package to make it so it plots the polygons separately without connecting them?

Comment: I have not any quick solution. :(

Comment: I can't seem to find one either. Oh well, thanks for trying! I sincerely appreciate it!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here you are:

[image]

Corresponding to the file: https://we.tl/t-VwJfcSCBsj

#### Background

I first tried to cluster your data using [DBSCAN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBSCAN) but as the space between natural consecutive points may be larger than spaces between two patches, it's non-sense to try to extract patches based on this algorithm. As we say in data science: "garbage in, garbage out".

Here's an example of the clustering result with `eps=0.0008` which visually correspond to the maximal curvature of the ordered nearest neighbors curve:

[image]

And the clustering results:

[image]

That's reason enough for you to manually fix your data.

The best thing you can do is to load your CSV file into a GIS software such a [QGIS](https://www.qgis.org/en/site/) for convenience (Main menu: "Layer" > "Add Layer" > "Add Delimited Text Layer..."), export your newly crated layer to, e.g. a [GeoPackage](https://www.geopackage.org/) file on the disk and then, click the [pencil](https://docs.qgis.org/3.22/en/_images/mActionToggleEditing.png) to enter the edit mode.

Open your [attribute table](https://docs.qgis.org/3.22/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/attribute_table.html) by a right click on your layer in the Layers panel on the left.

Then, create a new field (i.e. column) called, e.g. "island" as numeric using the "[New field](https://docs.qgis.org/3.22/en/_images/mActionNewAttribute.png)" button. Based on your first image, go the small islands. These are where the "jump lines" are going across your figure. Select the points that you think are part of a single polygon, and in the attribute table, click the button "Move selection to top". In the top line, select the "island" field, set a value, and the click "Update selected features":

[image]

Redo until you have set all the islands a distinct value.

Save your modifications and file.

Export your layer (right click the layer in the Layer panel: "Export > Save Feature As...") to a new CSV file. This result is the one I shared above.

From what I've seen in the CSV, polygons vertices are correctly ordered so they can easily be plotted with Python (first image I shared is obtained with this code on the new classified CSV data):

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""
Created on Fri Dec 16 00:00:04 2022

@author: s.k.

LICENSE: MIT License - https://opensource.org/licenses/MIT 
Copyright (c) 2022-present s.k.
"""

import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from shapely import Polygon, MultiPolygon

filepath = '/home/username/classified_coords.csv'
figpath = '/home/username/figure.png'

df = pd.read_csv(filepath)
data = np.array(df1[['lon','lat']])
startx, starty = np.round(np.min(data, axis=0), 2)
endx, endy = np.round(np.max(data, axis=0), 2)

polygons = []
for i in df1['island'].unique():
    P =  Polygon(np.array(df1[df1['island']==i][['lon','lat']]))
    polygons.append(P)

MP = MultiPolygon(polygons)


def plot_multipolygon(MP):
    plt.rcParams['figure.figsize'] = (16,8)
    fig, axs = plt.subplots(1,1)
    for P in MP.geoms:
        axs.plot(*P.exterior.xy)

    axs.set_xlabel("lon")
    axs.set_ylabel("lat")
    axs.xaxis.set_ticks(np.arange(startx, endx, 0.02))
    axs.yaxis.set_ticks(np.arange(starty, endy, 0.02))
    axs.grid()
    fig.tight_layout()
    plt.savefig(figpath, bbox_inches='tight')
    
plot_multipolygon(MP)
```

And voilà!